# Create RAR archive in 17.10

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, archive, compression, rar

I used to be able to create a rar archive from a file or folder by just right-clicking on the file (in Nautilus) and choosing "Compress...". I had the option to choose the rar format, which I like because I can create password-protected archives.

But now, when I do the same procedure, the only formats that are available are "zip", "tar.gz", and "7z". Strange.

I checked that the newest versions of the packages `rar` and `unrar` are still installed on my system.

Is there a way to get back the ".rar" format as an option when I create an archive through Nautilus?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [file-roller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller).

You'll still need to have the package rar installed.

```
sudo apt install rar
```

Once it's installed, launch the app called "file-roller".

[image]
Then create a new archive using the menu and choose type "rar". Adding files to your archive is done using + icon.